# Is it okay for a man to straighten his hair?

Tags: tznius-modesty

Is a man allowed to use a flat iron to straighten his hair if the person doesn't like having curly hair?

Comment: Welcome to mi yodeya!

Comment: Why might this be prohibited? Please edit to clarify

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. || Are you asking about [crossdressing](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/lo-yilbash/info)? If you are, please [edit] your question to include that information, thanks.

Comment: In a few weeks my hair will be long enough start to curl into "perfect ringlets" all on their own. Once this happens I start to receive negative comments that I shouldn't beautify my hair like women do, people being under the assumption that I spend a lot of time and effort to do my hair to look feminine. When I explain that I'm growing out my hair to donate to cancer patients and that my hair naturally curls like that after getting out of the shower it usually stops the comments, but either way, not a fun discussion.

Answer (score 1):

kitzur shulchan aruch chapter 171 halacha 1

"It is forbiden for a man to wear even one garment that is designed as a woman's, although he is dressed in a manner that clearly indicates that he is a man." ... "This prohabition does not apply to clothes alone. A man is forbidden to wear or employ any ornament or beautifying practice that is unique to women in his particular community."

It would see such a feminine practice as straightening one's hair would be prohibited under the category of not wearing women's clothing...

Devarim 22:5 לֹא יִהְיֶה כְלִי גֶבֶר עַל אִשָּׁה וְלֹא יִלְבַּשׁ גֶּבֶר שִׂמְלַת אִשָּׁה כִּי תוֹעֲבַת יְהֹוָה אֱלֹהֶיךָ כָּל עֹשֵׂה אֵלֶּה

"No male article shall be on a woman, and a man shall not wear a woman's garment because whoever does this is an abomination before Hashem your G-d"